# Why are two pthreads in sync even without mutex?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, pthreads, mutex

I was trying to redo an example of threads. Here are the two functions that I am running from main one after another. They are the typical increment and decrement functions.

```
void* increment(void *arg)
{
    int incr_step = *(int*) arg;
    free(arg);

    unsigned long int i; 
    for(i=0; i<5;i++) {
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        counter = counter + incr_step;
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        printf("Thread ID %lu --> counter = %d\n", pthread_self(), counter);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return NULL;
}

void* decrement(void *arg)
{
    int decr_step = *(int*)arg;
    free(arg);

    unsigned long int i; 
    for(i=0; i<5;i++) {
        //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        counter = counter - decr_step;
        //pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        printf("Thread ID %lu--> counter = %d\n", pthread_self(), counter);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

In main I just create two pthreads and call these two functions in both of these threads one after another and of course I am also joining them. I have a global variable counter, which is initially 5, and I am testing with passing increment value as 3, and decrement value as 2. So if my threads were synchronized, my final value of counter would be 10(since an increment of 3 happens five times, so counter becomes 5 + 5*3 = 20 and a decrement of 2 happens five times, so counter becomes 20 - 5*2 = 10).

However I have commented the mutex statements and I expect my final value of counter(which was 10 if threads were in sync) to be a different value, but I keep getting 10 again. Why?

Comment: Ok, this is weird, now I initialized my counter to 1000 and the threads are out of sync as expected. Why when I initialize counter to a smaller value does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of accessing shared variables without synchronizing mechanisms like mutex lock is **non-deterministi**c.

It is **by chance** that you are seeing the value of the variable same as with the mutex lock.

**No initial conditions guarantee** that race conditions won't happen even if you don't implement synchronized access of shared variables by threads.